# What's the difference in to convert numeric for factor using factorize or Categorical?

Tags: python, pandas

What the difference between PandasFactorize and Pandas Categorical.
I readed the documentation but wasn't clear for me.

Comment: Do you have some code examples?

Comment: The first is a *function* and returns two arrays, the second is a *class*.